# Uncaught RangeError: maximum call stack size exceeded when opening dijit dialog

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm showing a dijit dialog whenever the selection changes in a dijit select.  The problem is that I get an "Uncaught Range Error: Maximum call stack exceeded" whenever the dialog is not manually closed (click the X in upper right corner of dialog) before making another selection in the dijit select.  I've tried hiding the dialog using the .hide() method prior to using the .show() method -- but I still get the same error.  Any ideas to prevent this error?

//template with select:

```
    <div>
    <br /><select name="selectMAS" style="width: 150px; height:20px;"
                                    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" data-dojo-attach-point="selectMAS" 
                    data-dojo-attach-event="onChange:MASChange"></select>
</div>
```

//code to open the dialog from select:

```
MASChange: function (evt) {
//show the dialog when the selection changes (content of the dialog changes with the selection)
NSRF.NSRFDialog.show();//NSRF created in postcreate of class


}
```

//Dialog template:

```
<div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" title="New Service Request Form" data-dojo-attach-point="NSRFDialog" class="nonModal">
        TEST
</div>
</div>
```

//Dialog Code:

```
define([
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
  "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
   "dojo/dom", "dojo/ready", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/on",
  "dojo/text!Templates/test.htm"
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
    dom, ready, style, on,
    NSRFTpl) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: NSRFTpl,

        postCreate: function () {

        },
        destroy: function () {

            this.inherited(arguments);
        },
       showForm: function () {
            //fill in some info in the form later
        },


    });
});
```

Thanks

looking at the call stack the error is occuring:
Select.js

```
    try {
    this.focusNode.focus()
} catch (a) {}
}, focusChild: function(a) {
        a && this.set("value", a.option)
    }, _getFirst: function() {
        var a = this._getChildren();
        return a.length ? a[0] : null
    }, _getLast: function() {
        var a =
```

init.js

```
    try {
    a.focus()
} catch (c) {}
}
}));
b(function() {
    var a = v.registerWin(r.get(document));
    c("ie") && d(window, "unload", function() {
        a && (a.remove(), a = null)
    })
});
s.focus = function(a) {
    v.focus(a)
};
for (var w in v) /^_/.test(w) || (s.focus[w] = "function" == typeof v[w] ? g.hitch(v, w) : v[w]);
v.watch(function(a, c, b) {
    s.focus[a] = b
});
return v
})
}, "dijit/hccss": function() {
    define(["dojo/dom-class",
```

Comment: Is there any code programmatically changing the value of the Select?  That will also fire change handlers.  The call stack would be much more meaningful running against an unminified version of Dojo...

Comment: The data source of the select is a memory store that changes when a radio button is clicked.  I dont see the error when the radio button is clicked.  Strangely the error occurs only when the select is changed and the dialog is already open.  I've also posted the unminified code in select.js and init.js where the range error occurs -- thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had an EnhancedGrid inside the Dialog and I experienced the same error: RangeError "Maximum call stack size exceeded".
Setting the "autofocus" property of the Dialog to false solved the problem.